# How can I detect the packer used in elf file

Tags: elf, packer

I want to know whether the packer had been used or not in elf file format.
If then, what is that packer? How can I detect it?

Please let me know your knowledge or know-how about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are facing this problem on Windows. But, in the case of you are dealing with GNU/Linux environment you should first use the "file" command to understand the type of the file then use "strings" command with "grep" pipe to identifity it's packer. Here are some of the identification strings that helped me identify the packer type.

- UPX - UPX0, UPX1, UPX2
- Aspack - aspack, adata
- NSPack - NSP0, NSP1, NSP2
- NTKrnl - NTKrnl Security Suite
- PECompact - PEC2, PECompact2
- Themida - Themida, aPa2Wa

On the other hand in Windows there are tools like [PEID](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD) or Detect Ut Easy([DIE](https://ntinfo.biz/)). They are very easy to use tools with great success rate.

Comment: He is asking about packed ELF binaries which implies Linux not Windows

Comment: For instance, let's say we want to find it is a UPX packed file we can easily use `grep UPX0 filename`, `grep UPX1 filename` etc. commands. Even this approach works in many cases, some malware can hide their packers and misdirect you. To be sure you must look into the sections and  the entry point of the file and find a pattern for the pack that are almost specific for each pack, but this is a very time consuming job if you are trying to identify the packer fast. So, the Windows tools are very helpful for identifying packers.